# Unable to discover and connect to ble device only in Asus tab

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I developed an Android app to scan and connect to a BLE device. I tested it in Micromax Tab and some other devices, it was working fine.

But recently I tested in ASUS tab (C 7.0), most of the time it fails to scan the BLE devices (Sometimes its working fine).

Currently I faced this issue only in ASUS tab, rest of the Mobiles and Tabs are working fine.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue?

I'm not even getting any warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the devices having Intel processor is having problems in BLE communication.

The devices having Mediatek, Qualcomm processor is better for BLE communication.